RPC Error during Hybrid Search in Milvus: Mismatch between Vector Types
I’m trying to perform hybrid search in Milvus using the following code:
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_milvus.retrievers import MilvusCollectionHybridSearchRetriever
from langchain_milvus.utils.sparse import BM25SparseEmbedding
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
import torch
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from database_operation import initialise_milvus, data_ingest_milvus_db, data_load_from_milvus
import time
from groq import Groq
import os, logging
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
from pymilvus import (
    Collection,
    CollectionSchema,
    DataType,
    FieldSchema,
    WeightedRanker,
    connections,
)

CONNECTION_URI = "http://localhost:19530"
# export OPENAI_API_KEY=<your_api_key>

folder_path = "/home/rndadmin/dev/test/"

def preprocess_document(docs):
    table_fragments = {}
    data_string = ''

    for doc in docs:
        if doc.page_content:
            # Extract and process HTML table fragments
            if doc.metadata.get("text_as_html", ''):
                table_data = doc.metadata.get("text_as_html", '')
                # Parse the HTML
                soup = BeautifulSoup(table_data, 'html.parser')

                # Remove style attributes
                for tag in soup.find_all(style=True):
                    del tag['style']

                # Remove extra white spaces
                for tag in soup.find_all(["th", "td"]):
                    if tag.string:
                        tag.string = tag.string.strip()

                # Get table ID or another unique identifier
                table_id = soup.find('table')['id'] if soup.find('table') else 'unknown'
                cleaned_table = str(soup.table)

                if table_id not in table_fragments:
                    table_fragments[table_id] = []
                table_fragments[table_id].append(cleaned_table)

            data_string += doc.page_content + "\n\n"

    # Combine table fragments
    combined_tables = []
    for table_id, fragments in table_fragments.items():
        combined_table = ''.join(fragments)
        combined_tables.append(combined_table)

    # Create final document with combined tables
    final_doc = docs[0]
    final_doc.page_content = data_string + "\n\n".join(combined_tables)
    source = docs[0].metadata.get("source", '')

    if source:
        file_path = Path(source)
        file_name = file_path.name  # storing only filename
        final_doc.metadata = {"source": file_name} if file_name else {"source": source}
    else:
        final_doc.metadata = {"source": source}

    final_doc = [final_doc]
    print(final_doc)
    return final_doc


def get_documents(folder_path):
    try:
        documents = []
        files = [ext for ext in os.listdir(folder_path)]
        print("Length of the file: {}".format(len(files)))

        for file in files:
            if ('.pdf' in file) and not file.startswith("~$"):
                full_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
                pdf_loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader(full_path, mode="elements", strategy="fast",)
                print("Processing this file-> {}".format(full_path))
                pdf_document = pdf_loader.load()
                pdf_document = preprocess_document(pdf_document)
                documents += pdf_document

        return documents
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Issue while processing this file :{}:: {}".format(full_path, ex))


def load_and_process_documents():
    documents = get_documents(folder_path)
    print('Files Loaded')

    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=300, chunk_overlap=100)
    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    return texts


texts = load_and_process_documents()
print(type(texts))

dense_embedding_func = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
text_contents = [doc.page_content for doc in texts]  # Extract text content from each Document
dense_dim = len(dense_embedding_func.embed_query(text_contents[1]))

corpus = str(texts)
print(type(corpus))
sparse_embedding_func = BM25SparseEmbedding(corpus=corpus)

connections.connect(uri=CONNECTION_URI)

pk_field = "doc_id"
dense_field = "dense_vector"
sparse_field = "sparse_vector"
text_field = "text"

fields = [
    FieldSchema(name=pk_field, dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, is_primary=True, auto_id=True, max_length=100),
    FieldSchema(name=dense_field, dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=dense_dim),
    FieldSchema(name=sparse_field, dtype=DataType.SPARSE_FLOAT_VECTOR),
    FieldSchema(name=text_field, dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=65_535),
]

schema = CollectionSchema(fields=fields, enable_dynamic_field=False)
collection = Collection(name="Galitt_test_hybrid", schema=schema, consistency_level="Strong")

dense_index = {"index_type": "FLAT", "metric_type": "IP"}
collection.create_index("dense_vector", dense_index)
sparse_index = {"index_type": "SPARSE_INVERTED_INDEX", "metric_type": "IP"}
collection.create_index("sparse_vector", sparse_index)
collection.flush()

entities = []
for text in text_contents:
    dense_vector = dense_embedding_func.embed_documents([text])[0]
    sparse_vector = sparse_embedding_func.embed_documents([text])[0]

    print(f"Dense Vector Type: {type(dense_vector)}")
    print(f"Sparse Vector Type: {type(sparse_vector)}")

    # Check the format of sparse_vector here
    print(f"Sparse Vector: {sparse_vector}")

    entity = {
        dense_field: dense_vector,
        sparse_field: sparse_vector,
        text_field: text,
    }
    entities.append(entity)
    print(entities)

# Filter out entities with empty sparse vectors
valid_entities = [entity for entity in entities if entity[sparse_field]]
print("Valid Entities after excluding empty sparse vectors")
print(valid_entities)

if valid_entities:
    collection.insert(valid_entities)
    print("Entities inserted in vector DB")
else:
    print("No valid entities to insert.")
    
collection.load()

sparse_search_params = {"metric_type": "IP"}
dense_search_params = {"metric_type": "IP", "params": {}}

retriever = MilvusCollectionHybridSearchRetriever(
    collection=collection,
    rerank=WeightedRanker(0.5, 0.5),
    anns_fields=[dense_field, sparse_field],
    field_embeddings=[dense_embedding_func, sparse_embedding_func],
    field_search_params=[dense_search_params, sparse_search_params],
    top_k=3,
    text_field=text_field,
)

result = retriever.invoke("What does SDA mean?")
print(result)

The retriever is created successfully, but when I query it, I encounter the following error:
RPC error: [hybrid_search], <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=fail to search on QueryNode 3: worker(3) query failed: Assert "static_cast(field_meta.get_data_type()) == static_cast(info.type())" at /go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/core/src/query/Plan.cpp:48
=> vector type must be the same, field sparse_vector - type VECTOR_SPARSE_FLOAT, search info type VECTOR_FLOAT)>

The error seems to indicate that there is a mismatch between the types of vectors being used for the search. Specifically, it looks like the sparse_vector field is of type VECTOR_SPARSE_FLOAT, but the search is expecting a VECTOR_FLOAT.
What I’ve tried:
•   Verified that both dense and sparse embeddings are generated correctly.
•   Ensured that the schema for the sparse_vector field is defined as SPARSE_FLOAT_VECTOR.

